# error when using nnetar function from forecast package

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following timeseries data:

```
is.ts(infy_df_subset_ts)
[1] TRUE
> infy_df_subset_ts
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 2573 
Frequency = 1 
   [1] 2272.648 2311.352 2285.300 2275.052 2205.600 2190.100 2164.448 2183.000 2223.400
  [10] 2242.948 2222.200 2205.448 2224.148 2202.352 2254.000 2235.148 2234.052 2241.000
  [19] 2244.400 2247.300 2268.948 2265.552 2269.300 2272.948 2357.052 2373.700 2361.248
  [28] 2351.248 2304.200 2284.648 2382.948 2376.100 2359.948 2310.900 2287.500 2237.700
```

.................

When i execute the nnetar function i get the following error:

```
nnetfit<-nnetar(infy_df_subset_ts,lambda = 0, maxit=150)
Error in nnet.default(x, y, linout = linout, trace = trace, ...) : 
  object 'VR_set_net' not found
```

I have tried reinstalling forecast package, but the error still crops up!
What am i missing here??

for reproducibilty : ex. taken from https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/3

```
library(fpp)
fit <- nnetar(sunspotarea)
Error in nnet.default(x, y, linout = linout, trace = trace, ...) : 
  object 'VR_set_net' not found
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the problem. I cannot replicate it using randomly generated data with the same structure.

Answer (score 4):

I once had this problem. What I had to do is reinstall the package nnet inside R. Try it with the following line of code.

```
install.packages("nnet")
```

Comment: What worked for me was to reinstall `forecast` package within the RStudio console.

`install.packages("forecast")`